# Nomenclature for elements of a continued fraction

Tags: terminology, continued-fractions

Another simple question about nomenclature:

I have a continued fraction for a quadratic irrational: < 0; 1, 2, 3 >
where < 1, 2, 3 > represents the periodic part.

If I want to refer to an element of the continued fraction (for example, the element with value 2), then is there a specific term for it?  "Convergents," unless I misunderstand, refer to the fractional parts used during the calculation of the continued fraction and does not refer to the elements of the final resulting continued fraction representation.  (Please correct me if I've misunderstood this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entries 1,2,3 are called the [**parital denominators**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Generalized_continued_fraction).  A **convergent** is what you get of you stop at some point, such as
$<0;1,2>$.